# ag-grid cell style based on dynamic condition

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am looking for dynamic rendering of cells in ag-grid based on a settable threshold value above which the cell is rendered green else red.

I tried the following:

```
<AgGridReact
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
  pagination={true}
  columnDefs={[
    { headerName: "SYMBOL", field: "symbol" },
    {
      headerName: "PRICE",
      field: "price",
      volatile: true,
      cellStyle: function (params) {
        if (params.value < threshold) {
          return { backgroundColor: "red" };
        } else {
          return { backgroundColor: "green" };
        }
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

and take input for threshold (which sets the state). However, even though the state changes no change happen in the `columnDefs`.

I am using `.applyTransactionAsync()` for high frequency updates. Hence upon using `.setColumnDefs()` the table does not show any data.

Is there any way that this cell styling happens based on a dynamic condition on dynamic data instead of a fixed one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AgGrid's [`context`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context/) to update dynamic value that can then be used to pass around the grid. Here is how you can reference the `context` object in your `cellStyle` callback.

```js
{
  headerName: "PRICE",
  field: "price",
  cellStyle: (params) => {
    if (params.value < params.context.threshold) {
      return { backgroundColor: "lightCoral" };
    } else {
      return { backgroundColor: "deepSkyBlue" };
    }
  }
}
```

Setting up `context` is easy

```js
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  rowData={rowData}
  context={{
    threshold
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Where `threshold` is a dynamic value that you can get from redux store or an API response for example. In the demo code below, you can update `threshold` locally using the value from the `input`.

```js
const [threshold, setThreshold] = React.useState(20);
const updateThreshold = () => {
  const inputEl = document.getElementById("thresholdInput");
  const newValue = parseFloat((inputEl as HTMLInputElement).value);
  setThreshold(newValue);
};

return (
  <>
    <input id="thresholdInput" defaultValue={threshold} />
    <button onClick={updateThreshold}>Update threshold</button>
    ...
  </>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63975972/ag-grid-cell-style-based-on-dynamic-condition]